Can't generate a simple CuSparseMatrixCOO using CUDA from Julia
At the moment I'm trying to build a COO using the CUSPARSE library. Looking at the documentation, and the function arguments, the way to create this is using the row and column indices followed by the values of each element and the matrix dimension.
using CUDA, SparseArrays

K_rows = [0, 1, 1, 2]
K_cols = [0, 0, 2, 1]
K_vals = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]
a = CUDA.CUSPARSE.CuSparseMatrixCOO{Float64,Int64}(
        CuArray(K_rows), CuArray(K_cols), CuArray(K_vals),
         (3,3)
)
display(a)

However, when running this code, the following error occurs:
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 4-element CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.DeviceMemory} at index [[4294967297, 8589934596, 1, 1]] 

Am I missing something trivial here?
Julia version is at 1.11.1

Cannot run CUDA on my device, but a guess is that this may have to do with julia's 1-indexing. Have you tried to change dims from (3,3) to (4,4), or change the row and columns vectors to start at 1 (K_rows.+=1 etc.)?

I tried, neither one-based index nor increase space works
